# Does using __declspec(selectany) with static data have any effect on the initalization order of that data?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm using a third party C++ library that requires the definition of a global array of structures for it to use. I don't like this design but I'm stuck with it.

```
LibStruct g_Structs[] = 
{
  { /* structure initialization data */ },
  { /* structure initialization data */ },
      // etc
};
int g_NumStructs = sizeof(g_Structs) / sizeof(g_Structs[0]);
```

I'd like to break this down a bit so that classes can supply a structure definition that applies for that class. This risks causing the static initialization fiasco unless the initialization is done safely using getters or after main() begins.

If I declare MyStructs for each class in the header file for that class as static data members with __declspec(selectany) attribute (Visual C++ specific) then it *seems* to work. Does the selectany attribute have an effect on the construction order of that data? Does the appearance of the selectany definition of the static data member before the global array actually mean that it's constructed in that order? Or does this behaviour just depend on which of the multiple selectany definitions gets thrown away by the linker? Are there any guarantees with selectany?

```
// In the header for Class1
static const LibStruct __declspec(selectany) Class1::m_MyStruct = { /* structure initialization data */ };

// In the header for Class2
static const LibStruct __declspec(selectany) Class2::m_MyStruct = { /* structure initialization data */ };

// Danger - potential for static initialization fiasco?
LibStruct g_Structs[] = 
{
    Class1::m_MyStruct,
    Class2::m_MyStruct,
    // etc
};
int g_NumStructs = sizeof(g_Structs) / sizeof(g_Structs[0]);
```

CLARIFICATION:

In this case MyStruct is a C style struct that has no constructors or virtual functions and only contains pointers which are all initialized to point to other global data or non-member functions. So the initialization of a global const MyStruct using = {} syntax shouldn't run any constructor code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding my own answer as there haven't been any other answers.

It seems that this code will work but only because the Microsoft compiler implementation chooses to initialize global const primitive data by mapping it into memory from the .data section of the executable image before any static initialization code runs. So it's implementation dependent, but dependent on the compiler's static initialization strategy, not the use of __declspec(selectany).

Stepping through the entry point of the application shows that this appears to be correct. The static const MyStruct objects are already initialized at the entry point but the global array is initialized later in static construction code.